# git doesn't auto commit when I pull

Tags: git, git-pull

for some reason whenever I pull from master, git will not auto commit the changes to my local branch.  I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/mate -w: /usr/bin/mate: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/mate -w'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

and I have to manually do the commit after pulling.  This only started since I set up my new machine and never happened on my old one.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have text mate installed?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Git can't find your text editor (TextMate). Make sure it's installed and that `mate` is on your path.

Comment: @Jubobs All those full paths make me think it's not a `$PATH` issue.

Comment: @Biffen TextMate may not even be installed on the OP's new machine, but Git may be configured to use it.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes. And that has nothing to do with the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: @Biffen You're right; the `$PATH` is not the problem here. The only  explanation why that absolute path shows up in the error message is that the OP must have passed it to `git config core.editor`, at some stage.

Comment: I don't have textmate installed.  I use RubyMine.  I have never done the command you listed.

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce your problem if I set my core editor in some toy local repository like so

```
git config core.editor "/usr/bin/mate -w"
```

and then try to run a command that uses the editor:

```
$ git commit
/usr/bin/mate -w: /usr/bin/mate: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/mate -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I'm getting this error because there is no file or directory called `/usr/bin/mate` on my machine (I don't have TextMate installed).

You're getting a similar error for a similar reason: either TextMate *is* installed on your machine but not at `/usr/bin/mate`, or it's not installed at all. You should either

1. use a text editor that's already installed on your machine; or,
2. if you insist on using TextMate, make sure that it is actually installed; then run

   ```
   git config core.editor "<path_to_mate> -w"
   ```

   Alternatively, add `mate` to your path and simply run

   ```
   git config core.editor "mate -w"
   ```

Comment: I am using Ruby mine as my text editor I don't have textmate installed anywhere

Comment: Did you use RubyMine as you editor for Git on your previous machine? I don't think Git allows you to use an IDE as its core editor.

Comment: Or do you mean that you use Git from within RubyMine?

Comment: I think that Vim is the default text editor for git on my machine.

Comment: You can find out for sure which editor Git is configured to use by running `git config core.editor`, but we're not getting anywhere because you haven't answered my question: in what sense do you use or want to use RubyMine with Git?

Comment: @ruby_newbie That is very weird... I just checked the Git source code and the message `There was a problem with the editor` is only used when there is a problem with your core editor (i.e. the editor that Git is configured to use). But if your core editor is `vim`, why is Git complaining about `mate`?... Please run the following test: `cd ~; mkdir test_git_editor && cd test_git_editor; git init; touch README; git add README; git commit`. If you get an error message then, what does it say?

Comment: that returns:   Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/acumendigital/test_git_editor/.git/
/usr/bin/mate -w: /usr/bin/mate: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/mate -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.