# git commit command hangs indefinitely

Tags: git, git-commit

When I tried to make a commit using `git commit`, the sublime text editor did open, I wrote the commit message and saved and closed the editor but the changes were not being committed. The terminal hanged at the `git commit`.

I searched the net and found someone with the same issue and applied the same fix without thinking anything. I ran the command:

```
git config --global core.editor "mate -w"
```

and now I have a new error when I run `git commit`:

> mate -w: 1: mate -w: mate: not found
>   error: There was a problem with the editor 'mate -w'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Please help. I am very new with git and using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: does git commit -m "comit message" work ?  Yes? there's some issue with your editor.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223074/git-doesnt-auto-commit-when-i-pull

Comment: @NLN- Yes it did work. Can you please help me solve the issue? What should I do ?

Comment: Did you actually close the editor, or just suspend it (with Ctrl-Z)?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen- I closed the editor( ctrl+q) after saving the contents.

Comment: Okay! So I ran git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w" command and everything is working now. Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 15):

Git runs a *lot* of external bits as part of a commit. While Git itself is unlikely to hang, any of the external parts it calls could, so in order of execution:

1. The `pre-commit` hook. This is a script at `$REPO_ROOT/.git/hooks/pre-commit` (it is **not** the `.sample` file! It has to be one named, exactly and only, `pre-commit`.) Check the contents of the script to see if it might hang.
2. The `prepare-commit-msg` hook. It's right next to the `pre-commit` hook, named like you'd expect. Same thing.
3. If you didn't pass `-m`, then your editor starts so you can input the message. Make sure that

   - The window isn't hidden somehow (offscreen, minimized, behind other windows)
   - The editor itself isn't hanging
4. The `commit-msg` hook. Same as the other hooks.
5. Commit signing. This step only runs if you specify `-S` with `git commit`, or if you have `commit.gpgsign = true`. You can check the latter with `git config commit.gpgsign`. This also depends on your GPG agent. Check:

   - If your agent uses a GUI to get your passphrase, the window isn't hidden, like with the editor.
   - The agent itself isn't hanging. I've had several issues with mine, a [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))-based one, hanging.
   - You can always kill your GPG agent. All it does is save your password briefly, so you don't need to enter it every time. When you `git commit` again, it'll start fresh; this may or may not help with your hanging.
6. The `post-commit` hook.

Note that I've *only* addressed manually creating commits. `merge` will also create commits, and it follows largely the same sequence, with [some different hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

In addition, Git itself can take a while if your repo is particularly large -- each commit is essentially a snapshot of all the files in it at a given time. If you judiciously use [`.gitignore`s](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to ignore things like built executables and *just* track the source code in your Git repo, it can help a lot. Note that this will break some editors: Visual Studio (the original, not VS Code) in particular has some issues with this kind of thing.

Comment: I Ctrl-D'd out of gpg signing curses prompt once, after which I had to kill `gpg-agent` process to get `git commit` to work again.

Comment: Just want to highlight @Waked comment. There was also a gpg agent update process that seemed to also be hanging. For me the problem started when initiating a commit from within vscode and it didn't bring the gpg auth shell into foreground. It timed out I believe which seems to have triggered the hang.

Answer (score 14):

for me it was a gpg signing session that was exited abruptly, and I had to kill the gpg session with

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question, but it sure helped me solving my problem.

Answer (score 9):

It could be you have a pre-commit hook that performs a long-running task.

Check `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and see what it does.

Comment: Also, you can skip the pre-commit hook using `git commit --no-verify` as a simple way to determine if it's the pre-commit hook that blocks git from proceeding

Answer (score 3):

`git commit` hanging indefinitely can also occur if you sign commits with `gpg` & `gpg-agent` is [misconfigured](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Git#Signing_commits) or has another problem.

On a hardened system using [hidepid](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Security#hidepid) setting `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` (which currently defaults to the `gtk2` pinentry dialog) works around issues with the `tty` dialogs.

Using `nano` as your editor in `~/.gitconfig` will be much less problematic than using a desktop editor:

```
[core]
        editor = nano
        pager = less -FXRS
```

Comment: This was the issue for me, gpg was waiting for a lock.
`rm ~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I use sublime for my commit messages and I found the problem was that a sublime window was opening but not appearing in the foreground (as it usually does). Simple solution but because it didn't work as usual it looked like it was hanging.

Comment: it seems to not answer the question. It should be a comment IMO.

Comment: Possibly not for this specific user, but it's the top question for googling "git commit hangs" and seems like the editor is a common problem in this situation - hopefully it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

### Solution Steps

#### 1. Check for GPG Lock Messages

Open your terminal and try to perform a GPG operation (like signing a test message). If you see repeated messages like `gpg: waiting for lock (held by [process_id]) ...`, it indicates a lock issue.

- **For example**:

```bash
❯ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign

gpg: waiting for lock (held by 3571) ...
gpg: waiting for lock (held by 3571) ...
gpg: waiting for lock (held by 3571) ...
```

#### 2. Locate and Remove Stale Lock Files

- **List Lock Files**:

  ```bash
  ls -l ~/.gnupg/*.lock
  ```
- **Remove the Identified Stale Lock File**:

  ```bash
  rm ~/.gnupg/[name-of-the-stale-lock-file].lock
  ```

#### 3. Restart GPG-Agent

After removing any stale lock files, it's important to reset the state of the GPG agent.

- **Command to Restart GPG-Agent**:

  ```bash
  gpgconf --reload gpg-agent
  ```

#### 4. Test GPG Operations

To confirm if the issue is with GPG itself, try signing a simple test message:

- **Run**:

  ```bash
  echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
  ```

#### 5. Retry Committing in Git

With the GPG lock issue resolved, try committing your changes again in Git.

Referance link: [Git Commit Freeze Due to GPG Lock Issues](https://gist.github.com/bahadiraraz/f2fb15b07e0fce92d8d5a86ab33469f7)

Answer (score 0):

To help diagnose this you can run your command with `GIT_TRACE=1` prepended to it and it will show you what's hanging: e.g.

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -m "Adding github estimates"
13:30:33.907500 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git config alias.commit
13:30:33.915132 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git commit -m 'Adding github estimates'
13:30:33.925014 run-command.c:659       trace: run_command: gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau SECRET_KEY_ID
```