# GIT commands not responsing

Tags: git

my git stop working on ubuntu. It means I cannot commit, push, pull and so on. Whatever I want do, git stucks.

for instant I try command `git push origin -f` and terminal didnt responding and nothing print, I can only cancel action with ctrl + c. Same behaviour with other actions. I tried complete uninstall GIT with pruge, and install again but no helps. Also I tried another project, but this issue I have anywhere. Any idea how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: What version of git do you have? Try `git --version` on your terminal. If this responds in time then your git is fine. Maybe you're just working with a bad network. Do you say you can't commit too? Then it might be an issue with your OS and git. Also, don't be a child and take your anger here on SO (by saying git sucks, bladenly.)

Comment: Hi, I am using 2.25.1. Btw I wrote stucks not sucks. Maybe I just use wrong word bcs english is not my native, but I mean stuck like stuck in door for instance :)

Comment: Ah! Now I read again - yes, you did say "stucks". I'm sorry. Anyway, as git gives you a response git should be fine, it could be something else. Does `git commit -m "commit message"` work?

Comment: Also, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275804/git-commit-command-hangs-indefinitely) answer your question?

Comment: @clmno thank you for the effort but I resolve it with os reinstall because I didn't fix it in decent time and I couldn't continue in work.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry again for my "mis-reading" of the word stucks.

Comment: @clmno no problem :)